# How does an airflow sensor work?

Tags: forces, sensor, piezoelectric

[image]

There are 4 piezoresistive sensors placed at A, B, C and D.

Comment: Sensors like that generally measure a change in capacitance. That seems like a really strange design for an airflow sensor though. It's more akin to an accelerometer or gyroscope.

Comment: Where is this figure from? (Figures taken from other sources should always be properly attributed and linked if possible. This might also help people better understand the physics context for the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Fluid velocity around a "bluff" body causes vortices to alternately shed on one side of the body, then the other, causing a very slight wiggle as shown in diagram "c".  The frequency of the vortex shedding is related to the flow rate passing the bluff body.  For more information, see [this](https://www.omega.com/en-us/resources/vortex-flow-meter).

Answer (score 0):

A piezoresistive sensor changes resistance as function of strain. This can be used to determine pressure. Airflow can be can be determined by static or differential pressure measurements.